# Процедура для наполнения таблицы MS SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Необходимо заполнить таблицу customers  1 миллионом строк , а связанную таблицу Payments на каждого пользователя по 6 платежей. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXiXV.jpg

Результат таблицы customers, не понимаю что творится с id
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhkuu.jpg

А payments вообще не работает.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ud1N.jpg

Возможно дело во вложенном цикле, прошу подсказать оптимальное решение ибо не имею опыта в написании подобных процедур.

Comment: Скриншоты ни о чём - публикуйте код форматированным текстом, данные форматированной таблицей. *не понимаю что творится с id* А что с ним?

Comment: Просто в данный момент не у компьютера, обязательно исправлю ,почему такое огромное значение Id в customers

Comment: Выкладывайте: CREATE TABLE обеих таблиц, INSERT INTO с исходными данными (если таблицы исходно не пусты, по 2-3 записи) и желаемый результат (количества есссно сократить до "вставить 2-3 строки в customers и по 2 строки на один id в Payments").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример реализации указанной операции.

1. Создание таблиц.

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers (cus_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
                        name VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TABLE payments (pay_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
                       cus_id INT,
                       amount INT,
                       FOREIGN KEY (cus_id) REFERENCES customers (cus_id));
```

2. Создание (временного) триггера, который будет обеспечивать вставку связанных записей (по 2 штуки на одну основную запись).

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr
ON customers
AFTER INSERT
AS
WITH cte AS ( SELECT 1 num 
              UNION ALL
              SELECT num + 1 FROM cte WHERE num < 2 )
INSERT INTO payments (cus_id, amount)
SELECT INSERTED.cus_id, RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1000
FROM INSERTED
CROSS JOIN cte;
```

3. Вставка данных в основную таблицу (5 штук). Триггер вставит связанные записи в зависимую.

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT 1 num 
              UNION ALL
              SELECT num + 1 FROM cte WHERE num < 5 )
INSERT INTO customers (name)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), NEWID())
FROM cte;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c8903c8143c1fb39a1fda24c455751f6